# How to get distance of driven route?

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I am developing an iOS app using Rubymotion. In this app I am trying to calculate the distance traveled. I am using the below code and in the simulator (freeway drive) it returns good numbers but when trying it out for real in my car it sometimes stop counting midway through.

```
BW::Location.get(distance_filter: 2, desired_accuracy: :best_for_navigation) do |result|

 if in_motion(result[:to].speed)

  if result[:to].distanceFromLocation(result[:from]) < 40

   @distance += result[:to].distanceFromLocation(result[:from])

  end

 end

end
```

I tried this code too and it feels like there is less things that can go wrong?
Since I am using the distance_filter of 2 then I thought I could just increment by 2 each time I get new coordinates? Is this ok?

```
BW::Location.get(distance_filter: 2, desired_accuracy: :best_for_navigation) do |result|

 if in_motion(result[:to].speed)

  if result[:to].distanceFromLocation(result[:from]) < 40

   @distance += 2

  end

 end
```

The two methods output to different numbers.

Comment: Different numbers for the two methods seems clear to me. In method 2, you are ignoring the actual distance travelled. the distance travelled should not be less than the threshold, but may be much greater.

Comment: Ah ok, so the distance filter is a Minimum value then. Any idea why it never fails on simulator and freeway drive but fails on device?

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a new gem that can make this a lot easier:

https://github.com/willrax/motion-distance

You set it up like this:

```
@distance = Motion::Distance.new
@distance.activity_type = CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation #for driving
```

Then you call 'get' to get the distance travelled (in meters)

```
@distance.get do |location|
  puts location[:total]
end
```